# MS-Access - DLookup using values entered on form

Tags: ms-access, lookup, ms-access-forms

I am a complete novice with no experience of building a database.  I have been following a few online tutorials to help with a little project I want to work on.

Here is a pic of my current table relationships:
[image: DB Schema]

I have a form where I want to enter invoice details.  I want to be able to select a product from a drop-down and for it to automatically populate a text box with the cost.  The problem i have is, depending on the customer, the cost can be different.

Here is a pic of my form:
[image: Form]

I have tried using DLookUp in the Unit Price field but i just can't seem to get the hang of it.

Basically, in pseudo code, i want the unit price field to:
Select  From tblPrices Where PriceID =

I've tried:

```
=DLookUp([Product],"tblPrices","PriceID = " & [Forms]![tblInvoice]![SalesTypeID])
```

but it is returning the ID of the selected from product in the form from the Products table ?!

Comment: Forget about the form for now and back up to step 1 of DB Design: **table layout**. This site isn't the right place for learning with no prior knowledge, but some feedback: at first glance (but without seeing the data) the tables look okay **except for tblPrices**).  Delete it and start over. There's no short way for me to explain why it's wrong, but basically, **you're using each product as a field name when each product should be a record**. I'm curious to see what data you've put in tblPrices?  You need to find a good tutorial to walk through the basics of database design.Forms come later.

Comment: I see no SalesTypeID in your schema - where are you getting that from?If you want the Price in Dlookup why are you trying to pull the Product field?

Comment: @Rob - You made good effort, but you need to begin at the beginning. This basic free tutorial looks decent: [**QuackIt: Microsoft Access Tutorial**](https://www.quackit.com/microsoft_access/tutorial/). But **before that** watch this video on [**DB Planning**](https://youtu.be/i72fVNqfWL4) and perhaps [Microsoft's **Database Design Basics**](https://support.office.com/article/database-design-basics-eb2159cf-1e30-401a-8084-bd4f9c9ca1f5).

Comment: ...more advanced but also important (and what's wrong with tblPrices) is: [Microsoft's **Database Normalization Basics**](https://support.microsoft.com/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  (Technically, normalization is done to existing databases but the concept may be helpful now.)